# Allure Framework: Expected at least 1 argument, got 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework, allure

I have installed the robot framework and related libraries. Then I have installed the allure framework.
I have followed the following command in cmd prompt to install allure framework,

> pip install allure-robotframework
> robot --listener 'allure_robotframework;./results/allure'

But when I run the second command, it displays below error message

[ ERROR ] Expected at least 1 argument, got 0.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the command you're running it seems you're missing the tests that need to be executed.

make sure to pass the tests folder/suite to be executed as parameter:

`robot --listener 'allure_robotframework;./results/allure' tests/foo/baz.robot`

Comment: Do I need to run this command in the cmd prompt or in the terminal of the PyCharm IDE?? I ran this in both places. When I run on the terminal, it is compiled successfully and when I run it on the cmd prompt, it displays below error message;                                           Parsing 'TestCases\TryOne.robot' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.                   And then, I ran this command--> allure serve ./Results/allure  to generate the report, but it displays an empty report. What I am doing wrong??

Comment: I found the solution to my last question. Thank you very much for your answer. It was helpful for me.